# How to pass an Arraylist as a parameter into a method in Java?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java.

**Edit:**Sorry Guys. I realise what went wrong now. I am grateful for all your great answers. At the same time,  I am terribly sorry for wasting your precious time. Problem Solved now.

**Notice that I have written lines of code to obtain the Arraylist "list1" below , but I avoid copying and pasting it here, as those codes are lengthy**

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
  class ProDat{
     public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {                
             //obtain an Arraylist of String, named it "list1"
             produceFile(list1 , "filename.txt", "Column 1 \t\t Column 2\n");
       }

      //this method will take the Arraylist parameter and produce an output textfile
     public void produceFile(ArrayList<String> list, String str1 , String str2) {
    Collection<String> noDups_list = new HashSet<String> (list);
    try {
        File output = new File(str1);

        if(!output.exists())    {
        output.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedWriter b1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(str1));
        b1.write(str2);

        for(String temp: noDups_list)   {
        b1.write(temp + "\t\t" + Collections.frequency(list, temp) +
            "\n");
        }
    } catch(IOException e)  {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.get.Message());
    }
    }
```

}

My problem is that: everytime I try to compile this. I kept getting this error: illegal start of expression on the line - 
    "public void produceFile(ArrayList list, String str1 , String str2)"

Please someone correct me what went wrong.

Comment: Correct e.get.Message() to e.getMessage()

Comment: I can not believe that this question got 5 answers in 7 minutes. It should've gotten one comment and got closed.

Comment: I am terribly sorry. I am only a beginner in Java. I have spent a long time on this code and still wasnt able to understand why cant I pass the Arraylist as a parameter ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calling from `static` `main` method, make `produceFile` a `static` method:

```
public static void produceFile(..)
```

Or otherwise change your `main` method to instantiate `ProDat` instance and then call member method:

```
main(..)
{
ProDat obj = new ProDat();
obj.produceFile(..);
}
```

Comment: This is only [one of the problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16650522/474189), however.

Comment: I changed it to static and i am still getting the same error: illgeal start of expression

Comment: @user2394904 You need to [initialize your `list1` variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16650522/474189) too. Are you reading all your answers?

Comment: @user2394904 correct e.get.Message() to e.getMessage() in catch(IOException e)  {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.get.Message());
    }

Comment: @user2394904 Are you sure you have correctly pasted your code? The last line in your code `e.get.Message()` is buggy and `list` initialization code is not given, verify once.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** (bad code)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

   // edited here            
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
         produceFile(list1 , "filename.txt", "Column 1 \t\t Column 2\n");
   }

public static void produceFile //... etc note the "static" modifier
```

Comment: Why do I need Arrays.asList(args) ? Sorry I didnt put the code on how I obtain an ArrayList list1 because it is too lengthy.

Comment: I just added that as a placeholder for whatever logic you employ to generate the List you pass as 1st argument of method _produceFile_. You don't need that as long as you pass a List<String> as argument. In fact my code is incorrect as it doesn't point out that the argument should be a List (now it's an ArrayList). Editing now but you got better answers already anyway...

Answer (score 0):

static method can only call static methods

public static void produceFile((ArrayList list, String str1 , String str2)

if you want to call non static method from static method Go for below

```
ProDat proDat = new ProDat();

proDat.produceFile(list1 , "filename.txt", "Column 1 \t\t Column 2\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems with your class:

1. Your `produceFile` method must be static to call it from `main`.

   ```
   public static void produceFile(ArrayList<String> list, ...
   ```
2. You need to initialize your `list1` variable:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   produceFile(list1, "filename.txt", "Column 1 \t\t Column 2\n");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You method `produceFile()` should be `static`, as you are calling it directly from `main()` method.
If you will make an object of your in this way and then called your method, then it will not give you any error.

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
class ProDat obj = new ProDat();
produceFile(a , "filename.txt", "Column 1 \t\t Column 2\n");
}
```

Otherwise follow your  way.

```
class ProDat{
     public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
              ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            //add elements or data in this list                  
           // e.g list.add("product");  
             produceFile(list1 , "filename.txt", "Column 1 \t\t Column 2\n");
       }

     public static void produceFile(ArrayList<String> list, String str1 , String str2) {
    Collection<String> noDups_list = new HashSet<String> (list);
    try {
        File output = new File(str1);

        if(!output.exists())    {
        output.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedWriter b1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(str1));
        b1.write(str2);

        for(String temp: noDups_list)   {
        b1.write(temp + "\t\t" + Collections.frequency(list, temp) +
            "\n");
        }
    } catch(IOException e)  {
      //  System.err.println("Error: " + e.get.Message());
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: I changed it public static void produceFile(). But I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to either instantiate a `ProDat` object in your main method and call `produceFile()` on that or make the `produceFile()` method static.